# SQL Server Agent Job and gsutil

Tags: sql-server, google-cloud-storage, gsutil

I can successfully run a gsutil command with a windows domain account from the command line in Windows (setting up service account key etc.). When I try to run the same command from a SQL Agent Job using a CmdExec task the job hangs and doesn't complete. I can't see any logging so have no clue what it's waiting for. I've setup the job to run with the same Proxy User that i use to run the gsutil command manually.

Any ideas how I can get this to work or how to see more logging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using standalone gsutil? Or did you get it as part of installing the Cloud SDK (gcloud)?

If the job hangs for a long time, it could be stuck retrying multiple times. To test if this is the case, you can set the num_retries option to be very small, but above 0 (e.g. 1) either in your `.boto` file or the the command arguments via this option:

```
gsutil -o 'Boto:num_retries=1' <rest of command here...>
```

A second thing to note (at least for the version of gsutil that doesn't come with gcloud) is that gsutil looks for your boto config file (which specifies the credentials it should use) in your home directory by default. If you're running gsutil as a different user (maybe your SQL Agent Job runs as its own dedicated user?), it will look for a `.boto` file in **that** user's home directory. The same should apply for the gcloud version -- gcloud uses credentials based on the user executing it. You can avoid this by copying your .boto file to somewhere that the job has permission to read from, along with setting the BOTO_CONFIG environment variable to that path before running gsutil. From the cmd shell, this would look something like:

```
set BOTO_CONFIG=C:\some\path\.boto && gsutil <rest of command here...>
```

Note: If you're not sure which boto config file you're normally using, you can find out by running `gsutil version -l` and looking at the line that displays your config path(s).

Comment: Thanks for that. It turned out the BOTO_CONFIG was the issue.